# Application of Spar varnish on interior window sills

Tags: windows

I redid the polyurethane finish on my interior pine windowsills, which had some mildew, discoloration, and peeled finish from repeated wetting due to frost buildup on very cold winter nights. I sanded to bare wood, then applied indoor/outdoor satin spar urethane rather than polyurethane, for its resistance to moisture.  The problem is that the spar urethane significantly darkened the bare wood, contrasting with the blonde color of the previous polyurethaned pine.  It looks very blotchy, and I want to redo it.

The easiest thing may be to use a chemical stripper to remove the spar urethane finish, then re-finish.  My Questions:  How do I prevent the wood from darkening again?  Would a wood conditioner, like one might use before staining, do the trick?  And should I not be using spar urethane in the first place?

Comment: Spar varnish is **for spars**.   Spar varnish is *not* some awesomer hipster deluxe version of regular varnish.  It actually compromises away several desirable qualities of varnish, in order to get other qualities needed by **spars**.

Answer (score 1):

Spar varnish is optimized for outdoor use. It isn't as tough as indoor varnishes, but it is more flexible so it survives weatherng better, and it generally contains UV blocking additives which (partly) protect it  from chemical breakdown due to sunlight.

If that trade-off is acceptable, there is no reason you can't use it indoors. It may not be the best choice, but depending on your needs it may be more than good enough.

When I redid the trim around one set of windows, I explicitly chose to use spar varnish as the top coats because part of the trim is effectively outdoors and I wanted that weather protection. Then, since I happened to have it on hand, I've used the leftovers on some other projects where I just wanted the look of an oil-based varnish and wasn't especially worried about friction wear.

Tools for tasks... But if the tool works well for the task you need to do, go for it, even if that isn't what someone else uses that tool for.

Note that spar varnish is generally oil based, and *will* add color that water-based poly does not.